# Скрывать или удалять HTML элемент (fontawesome)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fontawesome

Вопрос теоретический.
Работаю с иконкой-спиннером fontawesome. Классика, показать во время запроса контента и скрыть при отображении контента. Большую часть времени его не видно.
С точки зрения производительности, общей для страницы и в момент загрузки контента (активации иконки), что лучше, скрывать/показывать или создавать/удалять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во всех случаях, что я встречал(плагины, другие сайты, примеры кода) скрывают просто. Ну и не перестраивается DOM, я думаю можно записать в плюс, если на странице много контента. Плюс код не будет его постоянно прикреплять и откреплять, а всего лишь раз загрузит и будет далее использовать. Да и вообще если возмоожно решить задачу с css я бы предпочел избегать js.